# Perl script can't load CSV file

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a subroutine in a Perl script that opens a csv file and reads the values into a hash table. The script is currently running without a problem on a Windows 2003 server. I am trying to get the script running on a Windows 2008 R2 server. When I run the script on the R2, it fails with the following error: Can't locate object method "getLine" via package "C:\file\test.csv" (perhaps you forgot to load "C:\file\test.csv)

I am running the script from the command line in the directory containing both the Perl script and the csv file. I am able to use the move() function to rename the csv file. Obviously, the csv file is being found, it's just not being read.

```
sub csv_file_hashref {
   my ($filename) = @_;
   my $csv_fh = IO::File->new($filename, 'r');
   my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ();
   my %output_hash;
   while(my $colref = $csv->getline ($filename))
   {
      $output_hash{shift @{$colref}} = $colref;
   }

   return \%output_hash;                        # return a reference to the hash
}
```

I have confirmed that the correct file name with full directory is in $filename. I've alos ensured that the IO::File module is installed. Why won't this code open the csv file?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getline`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS#getline) takes a filehandle as an argument, but you're passing the file *name*. Change

```
while(my $colref = $csv->getline ($filename))
```

to

```
while(my $colref = $csv->getline ($csv_fh))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`IO::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aFile) module is sometimes helpful if you want to treat your file handle as an object, but it is best in general to use Perl's native `open` operator.

As has been said, the problem is that you aren't using your file handle after opening the file: you should be passing it to [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV)'s `getline` method.

In addition, you are setting the value of the hash elements to array reference `$colref` instead of the value of the second element of the array it refers to.

Here's a tidied-up version of your subroutine with these points fixed.

```
sub csv_file_hashref {
   my ($filename) = @_;

   open my $csv_fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};
   my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;
   my %output_hash;

   while (my $row = $csv->getline($csv_fh)) {
      $output_hash{$row->[0]} = $row->[1];
   }

   return \%output_hash;
}
```

Comment: This line doesn't match the OP's intent: `$output_hash{$row->[0]} = $row->[1];`.  Looks like she had a list of values where the first was the key